# I want to Deserialize stream as contact in windows phone 7 c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, serialization, contacts, isolatedstorage

I Serialized Contact and Saved it in text file in The Isolated Store

I want to Deserialize it back as Contact

I tried this Code but I get error :

> Error 1   The type 'Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contact' has no
>   constructors

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Contact));
                    return reader.EndOfStream
                          ? new Contact()// error
                         : (Contact)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                }
```

is there another solution to get it back ?

Answer (score 3):

That looks like it is not intended for this purpose; all the properties are `get`, and there is no (public) constructor. `XmlSerializer` *will not* work on that.

IMO your best option is to create something of your own that looks *like* that class, but is serialization-friendly.